# MVC 5 view cannot see html image when using append div

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using ASP.net MVC5. (Level: Novice)

I am trying to create a div that contains an image using a JavaScript function. So I have the following code:

```
function showLoadingImage() {
        $('#submit_EmployeeDetails').append('<div id="loading-image"><img src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');  
    }
```

The function runs but all I can see on the view is the Alternative "Loading..." text not the actual image.

I have tried to put the image in to my view manually using the following code and I can see the image perfectly fine.

```
<div>
    <img src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" /> 
</div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the image doesn't show using the showLoadingImage function?

Many Thnks.

Comment: Remove the `~` when adding the element in the script `<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" ...`

Answer (score 0):

Path is wrongly constructed as view is unable to resolve `~`,so change it to

```
var path='<div id="loading-image"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>'

$('#submit_EmployeeDetails').append(path);
```

Side note:

If you want to dynamically add image then make it like this

```
var path="<div id='loading-image'><img src='/images/" + img.gif "' alt='Loading...' /></div>"
```